# How to clear cache in Sitecore

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I updated the `RichText commands.js` file under `/sitecore/shell/controls/rich text editor`.

I have copied it to the production environment, but my change isn't being applied. I am guessing JS is cached - how do I clear the cache? Site doesn't require a publish since content items weren't updated. Cleared the cache at  `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` too.

Browser caching cleared. Recycled the app pool and restarted the website as well.

Sitecore 7.2

Answer (score 2):

The javascript is cached in your browser not in Sitecore. Depending on your browser you can clear it from the toolbox (all of them have a clear cache option) or use the following shortcuts:

```
Firefox, Chrome, IE: Ctrl+Shift+Delete
Safari: Ctrl+Alt+E
```

Comment: @NomadTraveler are you sure the change was implemented correctly ? And you implemented it in the right rich text ?

Comment: The file was definitely copied across. Unless the sitecore JS files are minified into one?

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser caching.
A common solution is to add a ? to the script's src link.

For instance:
you can modify

```
 Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Default.aspx
```

and

```
\Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx
```

to have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/RichText Commands.js?v=152605"></script>
```

Also you can open your browser in incognito mode or to delete browser cache